# Displaying a picturebox? I don't see what I am doing wrong here

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I am checking to see if a server was reachable, then setting a picturebox's "Visible" boolean to true. However, when I first ran the code, no errors appeared, but no picturebox appeared either.

There is a offlinePic (Sets Visible boolean to true, and brings to front when the test fails)
There is a onlinePic  (Sets Visible boolean to true, and brings to front when the test passes)

I thought it would be possible that it was the server screwing things up, so I changed it to try with Google.com, and there is no difference.

```
private void Launcher_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestServerConnection();
    }
    public void TestServerConnection()
    {
        string url = "www.google.com";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = 15000;
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (onlinePic.Visible == false) onlinePic.Visible = true;
                onlinePic.BringToFront();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            if (offlinePic.Visible == false) offlinePic.Visible = true;
            offlinePic.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The format for your url is wrong.
www.google.com should be http://www.google.com

Everything else works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not all servers can respond on `HEAD` try to use `GET` instead in`request.Method`. And specify protocol `http` in the URL.

Comment: *_* You are useful. Kiitos! (Thank you!)